# How to avoid downtime during postgresql upgrade

Tags: postgresql, migration, upgrade, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.6

Im having a production PostgreSQL server 9.2, it has a few databases around 150GB. I want to upgrade this to 9.6, so I decided to upgrade this on QA server.

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.6.

Then block all the incoming connections.

Drop 9.6's cluster.

And upgrade 9.2's cluster to 9.6.

Everything is fine. I did this upgrade successfully.

But the thing is it took 7hrs to upgrade the databases, So here are my questions,

1.How can I avoid this huge downtime?

2.Any other ways to upgrade with minimal downtime?

Comment: Did you use `pg_upgrade` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html) ? Other ways, you can use `on-line upgrade` (http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/untangling-the-postgresql-upgrade/), in fact, it is a kind of replication.